# Logistic regression with chronologically available features

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-engineering

Normally we predict a target using static user features, here I am making serial predictions with increasing user behavior data.

I use 7 days as a period, and predict the user whether to be converted at the end of the period on a daily basis, using the feature data as of yesterday. I predict 6 times in total starting from day 2.

But this will have a problem, I'm using a logistic regression-scorecard model to train the complete historical data(of day 7s since the period's data is all available), and each feature will get a coefficient. But in production environment, feature data come day-by-day, eg. in day 2, I have feature_day1, to predict if_buy for the 1st time; in day 3, I have feature_day1 and feature_day2, to predict if_buy for the 2nd time. Technically, I can get a predicted result by setting the features of future days to null, but I doubt the correctness.  How to design this model so I can make predictions properly every day?

| note | date | day_no | user_id | if_buy | feature_day1 | feature_day2 | feature_day3 | feature_day4 | feature_day5 | feature_day6 | feature_day7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| complete_entry | 20220501 | 7 | 1000 | 0 | 9 | 5 | 9 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 6 |
| complete_entry | 20220501 | 7 | 1001 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 9 | 10 | 10 | 7 |
| complete_entry | 20220508 | 7 | 1010 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| complete_entry | 20220508 | 7 | 1011 | 0 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 10 | 7 | 2 | 2 |
| to_predict_1 | 20220509 | 1 | 1200 | ? | 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| to_predict_2 | 20220510 | 2 | 1200 | ? | 6 | 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| to_predict_3 | 20220511 | 3 | 1200 | ? | 6 | 8 | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| to_predict_4 | 20220512 | 4 | 1200 | ? | 6 | 8 | 1 | 5 |  |  |  |
| to_predict_5 | 20220513 | 5 | 1200 | ? | 6 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 9 |  |  |
| to_predict_6 | 20220514 | 6 | 1200 | ? | 6 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 6 |  |
| complete_entry | 20220515 | 7 | 1200 | 0 | 6 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 6 | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

Using a predicted value would introduce bias in your models.
For me you should train 7 different models :

- One with feature_day1 only
- One with feature_day1 and feature_day2
- One with feature_day1, feature_day2 and feature_day3
- etc ...
- The last one with all the feature_day1 to feature_day7

Then you have to investigate how to weight all your models to get the best predictions. I assume that your first model with only feature_day1 won't be the best, so give it low weight or don't use it at all.

You have to test different weights anyway